# Changing fonts in the body in beamer

Tags: beamer, fonts

I guess that it's a FAQ but I can't find the answer in the manual or here. How is it possible to change the fonts in the **body** of the text with beamer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a little trick:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamerfont{normal text}{size=\Huge, series=\bfseries}
\AtBeginDocument{\usebeamerfont{normal text}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```